# Absolute differences between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, notation

I have N vectors $x_1, x_2,...,x_N$ (all of equal length) and would like to compute the sum of absolute differences between consecutive vectors as well as between $x_N$ and $x_1$:

$|x_1 - x_2| + |x_2 - x_3| + ... + |x_{N-1} - x_N| + |x_N - x_1|$

and wonder about the best way to formulate this in mathematical terms. A straightforward way would be:

$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} |x_i - x_{i+1}| + |x_N - x_1|$.

Is there a more compact way to express this? Or to be more precise, is there a way to express that without the need for $|x_N - x_1|$ by a smarter indexing?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by an "absolute difference between vectors"

Comment: Sometimes authors will invoke modular arithmetic $\pmod N$ to get the point across here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: If there is a vector (1, -1) and (5, 1), then the absolute sum between these two vectors would be (4, 0). Does that make it clearer?

Comment: For example, you can make the quick note "where $i+1$ is calculated modulo $N$".

Comment: yes, that makes it clearer, thanks

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Would you mind adding your comment in a slightly extended version as an answer?! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, using modular arithmetic is probably the way to go. We can denote the ring of integers modulo $N$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,N-1\}.
\end{equation}
These numbers can be seen as all possible remainders when dividing by $N$.

Your sum can now be written down as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}} |x_{i+1}-x_{i+2}| = |x_1 -x_2|+\ldots+|x_N-x_1|.
\end{equation}